# Xcode tag Abuse Best Practices

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I have recently noticed that many questions on SO having to do with iOS or Mac development are abusing the [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) tag. My question is this: What are we (meaning those of us with > 500 rep) supposed to do? Should we just let the abuse continue, saying it's gone to far to be stopped, or should we ruthlessly scroll down the tag list, retagging every offender?

Comment: retag as you go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were given the retag ability for a reason.

You don't need to actively traverse the question list and retag anything in sight. But if you are active on the tag, retag questions which shouldn't have it as you see them.