# Should question about a framework/library etc. als contain the tag of the pragramming language it is written in?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see a lot of questions tagged like this: [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

jQuery is a *library* written in Javascript, the question is about using this library. So I think it should be enough to tag it with jQuery, since it has nothing to do with a problem using the *language* itself.

For me this is a problem because if I add [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) as my favourite tag I see a lot of "library questions" highlighted, although I am only interested in questions about the language (its syntax, what features it has, how to use it, etc.).

Another example is [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp)[java](/questions/tagged/java). I posted a question about [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) once and it was retagged to [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp)[java](/questions/tagged/java), with the comment: "please tag accordingly". I was a little upset, because it has nothing to do with Java and was purely a question about the usage of JSP.

It seems to me like many people are tagging their questions with a lot of tags to get the most attention. But this way I cannot use favourite tags to see the questions I am *really* interested in.

Is it considered appropriate to tag questions like this (library/framework+language)? Or is it better to tag only the library/framework? And what can we do about it?

Comment: As for what do do about it, you can ignore the framework tags you don't care about and then you won't have to see the questions. Or you can just scroll past them.

Comment: Closely related: [When not to use a tag that is inherently applicable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171585)

Answer (score 1):

If the language tag is there, the chances are that more people will notice the question.

In that respect, it is a good thing.

Yes, it is somewhat redundant, but that's not a bad thing in this case.

The exception would be when there are other tags that are more appropriate - though with a 5 tag limit, that's difficult to get to.

Comment: From my point of view, it is a bad thing because I see a lot of library questions highlighted when I am interested in questions about the language itself. I explained this in my question with "javascript" as a favourite tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it hurts to have the main language tag if there's sufficient room for it in lieu of more specific tags -- it opens it up to a wider audience that then may have a broader range of experience to edit/re-tag the question to move it back to a more specific audience if needs be.

Also, just picking an example I'm familiar with is [django](/questions/tagged/django) - frequently enough the question *isn't* specifically a problem with `django` itself, but is normally just someone using `django` and trying to do something in [python](/questions/tagged/python)... So in this case the `python` tag is necessary and the `django` tag becomes an indicator of context. Either tag by themselves wouldn't give the complete picture.

I think the above could possibly apply to your jQuery/javascript example... it just depends on what makes sense...If you're extending jQuery then you probably want both - if it's just using a feature of jQuery - you probably don't need javascript - however, I think you'd have a hard time stopping people trying to be helpful and adding the javascript tag in regardless... And IMHO I don't think it's that big a deal if they do anyway...